# What is the purpose of UIViewController.topLayoutGuide?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I'm writing a custom UIViewController that will have tabbar-like functionality (contains a control for switching between child views). When adding the child controllers, I also add the child's view to the container's view, and must size it so that it doesn't draw behind the control.

Reading the documentation, it would seem like setting the `topLayoutGuide` property is the ideal way to size these child controller views, but it is a read-only property, and nobody seems to have found a good way to override it. What is the purpose of this property if I can't use it to define the upper bounds of my controller's view?

Answer (score 0):

`topLayoutGuide` is used to adjust the height of ViewControllers when a `navigationBar` is visible, just like `bottomLayoutGuide` is for a `tabBar`.

You can use the layoutGuides with LayoutConstraints to autosize your views.

Answer (score 0):

`topLayoutGuide` (and `bottomLayoutGuide`) is a `NSLayoutConstraint` item similarly to views. Commonly used to constraint views to the top of the view controller (or bottom). Calulcated as follows

1. When a `viewController` is not embedded in a `navigationController`, `topLayoutGuide` begins on the bottom of `statusBar` if visible, else on the top edge of the `viewController`
2. When a `viewController` is embedded in a `navigationController`, `topLayoutGuide` begins on bottom of `statusBar` if opaque, else is calculated as in number 1.

For further reading refer to [length property of UILayoutSupport](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilayoutsupport/1622253-length)